# Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.ConvertProfileMeasuresMigration

Tags: sonarqube

RESOLVED: flushed sonar table.

When i go to `http://localhost:9000/setup` , after pressing "update" button , i get this error:

2014.08.06 04:08:03 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.ConvertProfileMeasuresMigration

Any suggestion please ?

Server: Centos 7
DB: Mysql

Mihai

Answer (score 1):

You're facing the following issue: [SONAR-5515](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5515). It will be fixed in the next version of SonarQube 4.5.

Meanwhile, you can run the SQL script given in the [last comment](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5515?focusedCommentId=351034&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-351034) of this ticket to fix your issue.